# ASP Button shows page fullscreen after postback in jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, dialog, postback

I have a jQuery dialog that displays an ASP form.
Within this form I've got a button. When I click this, some server side code should trigger and show results. But when I do this, on the postback, the dialog window dissapears and the dialog page is opened fullscreen in browser instead of a dialog.

Anyone who knows how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to keep the dialog opened after postback? If yes, see: [asp.net webforms and jquery: How to save/restore jquery state between postbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500728/asp-net-webforms-and-jquery-how-to-save-restore-jquery-state-between-postbacks). Briefly, you should remember the dialog state before pb, i. e. in a hidden field and restore it manually after.
AND, in the dialog form, set submit button's PostBackUrl to the page where the dialog was hosted in.